# How do I find if any one of the words in a file is in a very long string, which changes frequently in CMD batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have this filename which gets dropped into a directory on a windows share, where it needs to be located into the right location on the users' local machines, depending on if the filename has one of the keywords in it or not.

For instance:

```
z:\mailbox\in\Very_but#very-very!long#filenameWITH-keyword+in^it
```

where `z:` is accessible from a set of win-7 or win-10 machines. And on these machines, there are these two directories:

```
c:\incoming\special
c:\incoming\regular
```

if the filename has one of the keywords embedded in it, it needs to be copied into the `c:\incoming\special` folder, if not it needs to go into `c:\incoming\regular` folder.

my keywords are in a file, say, `c:\keywords.txt`
at any given time (checked every 5 minutes) there may be no files, or only one file in the `z:\mailbox\in` directory.

so, this is what I come up for, which is not working: (the batch file assumes there is a file to process, I haven't figured what to do, if there isn't one, yet)

```
dir /b z:\mailbox\in > tmp.out
set /p file=<tmp.out
del tmp.out

set keyword_found_flag=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%keyword in (c:\keywords.txt) do (

echo %file% | find /i "%%keyword"
if errorlevel=0 set keyword_found_flag=1

)
```

The errorlevel is always zero regardless if the keyword is found or not

```
IF keyword_found_flag=1 (
    copy z:\mailbox\in\%file% c:\incoming\special
) ELSE (
    copy z:\mailbox\in\%file% c:\incoming\regular
)
```

I am not sure what to do here. Any help is appreciated

Comment: `%%keyword` should throw an error.  It is invalid syntax.  You want `%%k`

Comment: Also, this looks like you might want to use `findstr` with at least `/g` and `/x` instead of your `for` loop.

Comment: Yes, I realized about %%k propblem. I wanted to make my code presentable but without knowing changed %%A to %%keyword and saw error messages. I was coming here to edit my question and saw the answer which worked totally for my purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use operator (`&&`) to set your flag if execution is match?

---

```bat
echo %file% | find /i "%%keyword" >nul && set keyword_found_flag=1
```

You also don't need create/delete tmp.out file for your process, use double for to for the file name in z:\mailbox\in and, and use another for to check file contains in c:\keywords.txt with file names in z:\mailbox\in...

```bat
@echo off

set "keyword_found_flag=" && for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('dir /on /b /a:-d "z:\mailbox\in\*.*"
')do for /F tokens^=* %%K in ('type c:\keywords.txt')do echo="%%~i"| find /i "%%~K" && (
     set "keyword_found_flag=1") || (set "keyword_found_flag=0")
```

---

Or...

```bat
@echo off 

set "keyword_found_flag=" && for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('dir /on /b /a: -d "z:\mailbox\in\*.*"
')do for /F tokens^=* %%K in ('type c:\keywords.txt')do echo="%%~i"|find /i "%%~K" >nul && (
set "keyword_found_flag=1" && copy /v "%%~dpnxi" "c:\incoming\special\" ) || (
set "keyword_found_flag=0" && copy /v "%%~dpnxi" "c:\incoming\regular\" )
```

Comment: Thank you.. Your code block in the middle worked as I wanted. I am not sure what was the problem with mine but I am glad to have a solution.

Comment: @MelBurslan so sorry my limited English..Thank you too for test..